# How to make a replacement, provided an inner rule applies

Tags: pattern-matching

Consider:

```
expr /. (b[a_] * c_f /; !FreeQ[c, d[a]] :> (c /. (d[a] :> e) ))
```

Here's how it works:  in `expr`, the products `b[a]*c`, with `c` being a large arbitrarily deep expression with head `f`, gets replaced with just `c` in which all the `d[a]`'s replaced with `e`.  However, this replacement is supposed to happen only if the arbitrarily deep expression `c` has at least one `d[a]` in it.

But, I am afraid that the `Condition` of `!FreeQ[c,d[a]]` together with the second `ReplaceAll` is making the pattern matcher/searcher scan through `c` twice.

Is there a way to achieve this task by making the pattern matcher search through `c` only once?

---

Follow up question: would it be any harder to achieve this task if the inner rule had more structure?

```
expr /. (b[a_] * c_f /; !FreeQ[c, d[___, a, ___]] :> (c /. (d[left___, a, right___] :> e[left, {b}, right]) ))
```

In this case `d` is more complicated, and the replacement is more precise.

Comment: Apart from the interesting intellectual problem, does the number of times the pattern engine traverses the expression actually impact performance or the result (perhaps because of side effects)?

Comment: By "scan through `f`" I assume you actually meant "scan through `c`". Yes, it appears such a scan would recur. Why have the `Condition` in the first place though?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes that's a typo.  Without the condition, the expression `b[a] f[(*stuff*)]` would unintentionally get transformed to `f[(*stuff*)]` even if there is no `d[a]` inside `f[(*stuff*)]`.  The `b[a]` pre-factor should disappear only if there is `d[a]` inside `f[(*stuff*)]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the concerns about performance degradation may in many cases be unwarranted, here is a way that would avoid double - traversal:

```
exp /. b[a_]*c_f :> With[{res = c /. d[a] :> e}, res /; res =!= c]
```

This uses the semantics of local variables shared between the body and the condition of the rule, and assumes that replacements change the original expression `c`. If the condition does not hold, the whole rule isn't considered matched, so is not applied.

Comment: This is nice, but doesn't checking  `res=!=c` require traversing through the whole expression again?

Comment: @QuantumDot It does, but this is done at even much lower level than what the pattern-matcher does, in the kernel. So for all intents and purposes, this does not count as another pattern-matching traversal, IMO.

Comment: I came up with another way to do it (posted as an answer); can you see if it is a viable alternative that prevents double traversal?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with another way to do this:

```
expr /. b[a_]*c_f :>
  Block[{$patternMatched},
    With[{result = c /. (d[a] :> ($patternMatched = True; e))}, 
     result /; $patternMatched]]
```

Once the outer pattern matches (`b[a_]*c_f`), a boolean is set up `$patternMatched`.  Then, if the inner pattern matches (`d[a]` appears inside `c`) then `$patternMatched` is set to `True`, so that the replacement is made.  If the inner pattern fails to match, the `Condition` fails, stopping the outer replacement from happening.

Comment: Looks like a valid alternative. Personally I try to avoid side effects, but this particular code looks fine to me.